# In Ruby, how to be warned of duplicate keys in hashes when loading a YAML document?

Tags: ruby, yaml

In the following Ruby example, is there a mode to have YAML ***NOT*** silently ignore the duplicate key 'one'?

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> str = '{ one: 1, one: 2 }'
=> "{ one: 1, one: 2 }"
irb(main):003:0> YAML.load(str)
=> {"one"=>2}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You'd have to decide how to rename the keys since hash keys have to be unique - I'd go for some workaround like manually looking for keys that are the same and renaming them before you do a `YAML::load`.

Answer (score 5):

Using Psych, you can traverse the AST tree to find duplicate keys. I'm using the following helper method in my test suite to validate that there are no duplicate keys in my i18n translations:

```rb
def duplicate_keys(file_or_content)
  yaml = file_or_content.is_a?(File) ? file_or_content.read : file_or_content
  duplicate_keys = []

  validator = ->(node, parent_path) do
    if node.is_a?(Psych::Nodes::Mapping)
      children = node.children.each_slice(2) # In a Mapping, every other child is the key node, the other is the value node.
      duplicates = children.map { |key_node, _value_node| key_node }.group_by(&:value).select { |_value, nodes| nodes.size > 1 }

      duplicates.each do |key, nodes|
        duplicate_key = {
          file: (file_or_content.path if file_or_content.is_a?(File)),
          key: parent_path + [key],
          occurrences: nodes.map { |occurrence| "line: #{occurrence.start_line + 1}" },
        }.compact

        duplicate_keys << duplicate_key
      end

      children.each { |key_node, value_node| validator.call(value_node, parent_path + [key_node.try(:value)].compact) }
    else
      node.children.to_a.each { |child| validator.call(child, parent_path) }
    end
  end

  ast = Psych.parse_stream(yaml)
  validator.call(ast, [])

  duplicate_keys
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very useful!

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution involving a linter, but I'm not sure it will be relevant to
you since it's not a 100% Ruby solution. I'll post it anyway since I don't know
any way to do this in Ruby:

You can use the [yamllint](http://yamllint.readthedocs.org/) command-line tool:

```
sudo pip install yamllint
```

Specifically, it has a rule `key-duplicates` that detects duplicated keys:

```
$ cat test.yml
{ one: 1, one: 2 }

$ yamllint test.yml
test.yml
  1:11      error    duplication of key "one" in mapping  (key-duplicates)
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the things I do to help maintain the YAML files I use, is write code to initially generate it from a known structure in Ruby. That gets me started.

Then, I'll write a little snippet that loads it and outputs what it parsed using either [PrettyPrint](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/prettyprint/1.9.2/frames) or [Awesome Print](http://rubydoc.info/gems/awesome_print/0.3.2/frames) so I can compare that to the file.

I also sort the fields as necessary to make it easy to look for duplicates.