# When converting Yaml to a Ruby hash how can I distinguish entries with the same key

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml

I have a yaml file which contains entries in a similar form to this. The entries represent change sets for a database and the key is the database name. The duplicates are needed since there may be multiple changes to a database which happen in a particular order.

```
exampleName:
  user: user
  version: 1
  artifact: example1
  order: 1
exampleName:
  user: user
  version: 1
  artifact: example2
  order: 4
aName:
  user: user2
  version: 12
  artifact: example3
  order: 3
```

I would like to be able to distinguish them by name and artifact such that both instances of exampleName would be recognised. However when I use YAML::load_file since they have the same key only the last one will be kept in the hash and the other one lost. Is there someway to have the key be a combination of the name and artifact when loading the yaml into a hash or do I need to manually parse the yaml. I have found one question vaguely related.

[In Ruby, how to be warned of duplicate keys in hashes when loading a YAML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911105/in-ruby-how-to-be-warned-of-duplicate-keys-in-hashes-when-loading-a-yaml-docume)

It seems like it might not be possible the way I would like it, but any work around would be great.

Comment: If it's a normal hash then values with the same keys overwrite each other. Do you not want to use a normal hash?

Comment: The problem is this is more of a bug fix in a larger structure of other processes so not using a normal hash might cause a lot of re-factoring, I'm open to suggestions of some other way of doing it though. I'm primarily a java programmer and not very competent in ruby so I don't really know how I could do it.

Comment: The [Yaml spec says](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id932806) “It is an error for two equal keys to appear in the same mapping node.” So what you have isn’t valid Yaml. It goes on to say “In such a case the YAML processor may continue, ignoring the second key: value pair and issuing an appropriate warning.” which isn’t what the current Ruby Yaml parser does, so arguably the current behaviour is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. You're right it seems that to do what I want I would need to restructure the yaml so the id is some other unique id since the yaml is invalid otherwise.

Comment: But that's how a normal hash *works*, it's no different than a Java map. You don't really have a YAML file in the traditional sense: you have a collection of records, within which order is important. It's a log file.

Comment: You're correct, it seems that as it is the duplicates will continue to be ignored by design so I should change the keys.

Comment: I don’t think it effects your question, but you need a space after your colons to have valid Yaml: `user: user`, not `user:user`.

Comment: In the actual code there are spaces, I will add them into the example as it currently does look pretty ugly :) thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to alter how the Yaml file is generated, or if you are able to preprocess it appropriately, you could create a file containing several [Yaml documents](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id897596). It would look something like this:

```yaml
exampleName:
  user: user
  version: 1
  artifact: example1
  order: 1
---
exampleName:
  user: user
  version: 1
  artifact: example2
  order: 4
---
aName:
  user: user2
  version: 12
  artifact: example3
  order: 3
```

Note how each document is separated from the others with `---`.

You can now parse this using [`YAML.load_stream`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_stream), which will give you an array of hashes:

```ruby
YAML.load_stream File.read('./your_yaml_file.yaml')
```

The result will be:

```
[{"exampleName"=>
   {"user"=>"user", "version"=>1, "artifact"=>"example1", "order"=>1}},
 {"exampleName"=>
   {"user"=>"user", "version"=>1, "artifact"=>"example2", "order"=>4}},
 {"aName"=>
   {"user"=>"user2", "version"=>12, "artifact"=>"example3", "order"=>3}}]
```

Comment: Ok thanks I will see if I can edit the yaml and experiment with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is `Psych` parser/AST-builder behind `YAML::load`.

If I was forced to use the “putrid” YAML as you do, I would take a look at [Psych::TreeBuilder](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/TreeBuilder.html) class. I would subclass it and re-implement `scalar` method. I never did so, but it looks like the right way. Since you were asked for any suggestion, here it is.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That seem like a definite option I will look into it. Thanks for your reply.